# Deletion using Linq to Mysql not happening

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Here is the code I used in my project for deleting record from a table 'account',

```
using (OneViewEntities context = new OneViewEntities())
            {
                var AccountDelete = (from a in context.accounts
                                     where a.id == accountId && a.userid == userId
                                     select a).SingleOrDefault();                    
                context.accounts.DeleteObject(AccountDelete);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
```

But this code throws an exception while executing the context.SaveChanges().
Here is the error details.

```
InnerException = {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT\n      `account`.`id`, \n      `account`.`isprimary`, \n      `account`.`na' at line 1"}
```

Comment: perhaps default is being returned? What happens if you change that SingleOrDefault to just Single to see if that throws an exception. (Single throws and exception if no records are found)

Comment: I am trying to debug it and the object is having data..  it throws this exception though...

Comment: Wrong database version?